# Generic Validation Component / Directive

Tags: angular

We are investigating converting from angularJS to Angular.  I am using angular 5 at the moment.

In AngularJS, we wrote a generic validation directive shown below as 'our-validation-message':

```
<our-control-group label="Our label">
    <input name="fieldC" id="fieldC" ng-model="test.fieldC" 
        class="form-control" ng-required="true"  autocomplete="off"
        ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" type="text" /> 
    <our-validation-message />
</our-control-group>
```

The programmer just pasted it like above and it was packed with functionality.

Of interest here it did a few things without a ton of boilerplate code:
a) it showed one and only one message for the field.
b) it did so only in a couple circumstances: there was an change attempt on the field or the form was submitted and that particular field is in error.

In AngularJS, it shared scope which I understand to be invalid in Angular.  I was also able to so things to the input element such as turn the field border red as long as the programmer adhered to the HTML structure above.  Also by convention we had a field that all programmers knew about called invalidSubmitAttempt.  This would be turned true in save methods when the user pressed save yet the form was invalid (our UX folks do not like the paradigm of disabling save and making users search for why).

Sorry if that long winded explanation was too much intro.  Here are my questions:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="heroPower">Hero Power</label>
    <input id="heroPower" name="heroPower" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="hero.power" placeholder="Power" required #heroPower="ngModel">

    <our-validation-message [control]="heroPower" [isInvalidFormSubmitted]="isInvalidFormSubmitted"></our-validation-message>
</div>
```

I was able to convert the directive.  However, I seem to have to have to pass in my field and variable for invalid form submit.  Can I:
a) have the component know based on parent it is contained in which field it is monitoring to eliminate this: [control]="heroPower" ?
b) have the component get access to the field's form so instead of passing a variable in, I can just set it like 'myform.invalidSubmitAttempt = true'.  This would eliminate [isInvalidFormSubmitted]="isInvalidFormSubmitted"

I know that is not a lot of code but we try and eliminate/automate everything we can.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In template driving form, add a reference with a # ex: inside

```
    <form #f="ngForm">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="heroPower">Hero Power</label>
<input id="heroPower" name="heroPower" class="form-control"  
 [(ngModel)]="hero.power" placeholder="Power" required #heroPower="ngModel">

<our-validation-message *ngIf="f.invalid"></our-validation-message>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Phillip.   I was hoping to find a solution that did not need repetitive logic.  Our 1.x solution only requires the directive be placed and it can figure out what input it is for and watch the submittedInvalid flag by itself.  Seems like maybe this cannot be done in new version?